# integrating admob to android at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I am trying to integrate admob for android in eclipse.
I followed the instructions from 
[here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en_US)

but now I i stuck with a run time error 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)

this is my logcat

ok after giving the unique id this is now the logcat is

```
10-02 02:44:13.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1457): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.skylite.ghanalivetv.Splash$PlaceholderFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.skylite.ghanalivetv-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.skylite.ghanalivetv-1, /system/lib]]
```

Can you please tell me how to solve it

Comment: You accidently deleted your link.

Comment: Can you post the catlog as well.?

Comment: Cross posted on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257779/integrating-admob-to-android-at-android-view-layoutinflater-createviewfromtagla) where it's ridiculously off-topic but currently still has the code link in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to learn how to read the log files since the error is quite clear from the logs.

It appears your class (PlaceholderFragment) either does not exist, is not public, is missing an empty (default) constructor or a combination thereof.

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment     com.skylite.ghanalivetv.Splash$PlaceholderFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public.
```

Learning to debug is a necessary skill that you will have to master as you start developing an app, otherwise you won't be able to write complex (or even simple) apps. You can't really outsource debugging to others :).

Comment: thanks to realize me in a nice and polite way that what should i have to do :) .

Answer (score 0):

Your stacktrace gives you the answer:

```
Binary XML file line #13: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.skylite.ghanalivetv.Splash$PlaceholderFragment
```

One of the elements in your layout (at line 13) has a duplicated android:id or android:tag

Comment: i have set the unique id and now above is my logcat's error